# Try catch does not work (always does catch code)

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

If anyone can help me I would be grateful! It should be converted the three EditText variables into strings and then integers. I added the exception because without it, the program crashed on startup. I'm not sure whether the problem is in the conversion of the variables, in my try catch code, or in both. Please help!

```
package boston.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TheBostonProjectActivity extends Activity {

public EditText aed, bed, ced;
public TextView dtv;
public int a, b, c;
public Button solve;
public double dis;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


        aed = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.etA));
                    try {
                        a = Integer.parseInt(aed.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            a = 0;
                        }
        bed = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.etB));
                    try {
                        b = Integer.parseInt(bed.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            b = 0;
                        }
        ced = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.etC));
                    try {
                        c = Integer.parseInt(ced.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            c = 0;
                        }

    solve = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.bsolve));

    solve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            dis = (b*b)-(4*a*c);
            dtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdis);
            dtv.setText("Discriminant:" + dis);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: What IS the problem you are talking about - crash on startup? Imho EditText might be uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get the text from EditTexts just after you created them (by calling setContentView). They are all empty - contain no text. And since

```
Integer.parseInt("");
```

Throws an exception, all your catch blocks are executed (and that means, that they actually work, not the contrary).

Comment: so..sorry if this is a dumb question but, how would i fix this? the three EditText fields (etA, etB, and etC) are defined by user inputs. So how would i correctly convert that to an integer?

Comment: The simplest way would be to move the code into onClickListener of your button.